# How to pass on demand data to datagrid virtualization

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, virtualization, ondemand

I'm using **data grid** to create one comparison window.The rows in the data grid will be like this

> clm1      clm2      clm3       clm4     ...

All decided in runtime. Also, there will be
2d and 3d image histogram profile and the number of clmns/rows all dynamic...

Since there can be hundreds/thousands of rows and indefinite clms I am using **datagrid virtualization**;.

Now my design is like when this window will be launched may 200 rows of data will be populated to the data grid at one go (each row memory can be of 50/100 mb each based on clms) --- So my plan is to keep the data’s in some cache file, and load it only when that particular row comes to view in data grid.

**So my doubt is how to identify which row is currently in view so that I can ask for the specific data from cache file.**

Comment: Add your code please.

Comment: actually there not much of code present now --- there is one simple datagrid for which I am making virtualization true.

Comment: my code behind will take all the rows data in a data table --- which may be of size 2/3 GB based on number of rows - and therotically there will not be any limit.   So I don't want to block the memory with this huge data - so was planning to keep in some cache file - and send the data to data grid on demand with view update